# Use Regular Expression to retrieve Url in the row with more than one Url

Tags: regex, url

This is an example string.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.evangelical-library.org.uk" target="_blank"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-22582 size-full" src="http://the7.dream-demo.com/main/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2014/05/show-04.png" alt="" width="372" height="225" /></a></p
```

There are `two Url in a row`

One is for PNG, the other is for a web page. I want to get the Png url like the pattern "http:.....png".

It simply uses `"http://.*?png"`, but it retrieves a string from the first `"http://"` URL to **the second Url with Png file extension**.

I can now do it using the condition `href and src` to identify which belongs to `Png url`. But it will miss a lot of png urls with other patterns like `<png>Png url</png>`.

**How could it be solved?** Thanks.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhmm, dont parse html with regex as Biffen commented on, but you can extract bits eg:

`(?<=href=")[^"]+.png`

will do a lookbehind for `href="` at the start of the pattern, match every character that isn't a `"` until the `.png` at the end.

Spending an hour learning regex will save you time coming here.

Comment: Lookahead should be for `src`, not `href`